# google drive used space report in google apps domain

Tags: api, google-drive-api

Anyone knows if it's possible to get a report with free/used google drive space for each user? Something similar to "account report" https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/#accounts_report but for Google drive?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no report autogenerated but all the data is available.

You can grab a list of all users in your Google Apps instance with the Provisioning API:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_organization_users_experimental

You can authenticate to Drive API as each user using a service account that has been granted domain-wide authority:
https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Lastly, you can determine the user's current usage as well as their quota using the about() API call:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

this will give you a real-time view of user usage and quota (as opposed to a report that can be up to 24 hours outdated)